# Filtering input files for Photoshop Image Processor

Tags: raw, image-processing, automation, photoshop-cs6

Is there a way to restrict the filetype that Photoshop Image Processor will process? I'm using CS6 and have a directory with a mix of RAW and JPG files, I only want to process the RAW files but can't see a way setting this option.

Comment: Only select or open the files you  **want** to work on. I am not sure what the problem is you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Image Processor lets you select folders only. You have to keep all files in one folder. Create subfolders (separate for RAW and separate for JPGs etc.).

You can easily sort all files based on their extension in File Explorer (sort folder content by "Type"), then drag & drop into specific folders.